# Pass SUDS method name form variable

Tags: python, suds

I am new to python and have some problem with invoking SOAP method using SUDS package. 
I have this Tk gui app, where from Treeview widget I select method name and pass parameter values from Entry widgets.
I can get method name in variable, but problem is, how to pass variable value as SUDS Method name?

I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sys
from suds.client import *


class SoapClass:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.client = Client('http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertWeight.asmx?WSDL', username='', password='', faults=False)

        Button(master, text='Call', command=self.request).pack()

    def request(self):

        methodName = 'ConvertWeight'

        #Here I would like to pass methodName variable
        response = self.client.service.ConvertWeight(80, 'Kilograms', 'Grams')

        print(response)

root = Tk()
app = SoapClass(root)


root.mainloop()
```

I would like to do this way:

```
methodName = 'ConvertWeight'

response = self.client.service.methodName(80, 'Kilograms', 'Grams')
```

And of course Web Service gives me:

**raise MethodNotFound(qn)**

**suds.MethodNotFound: Method not found:'ConvertWeights.ConvertWeightsSoap.methodName'**

How can I do this? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time digging the internet I found solution.

At first I looked up this:

```
params = client.factory.create('ConvertWeight')
```

and than adding needed parameters to this object.

Unfortunately  no luck, because as I investigated, my WSDL was broken, but `ImportDoctor` couldn't fix my WSDL and when calling `client.factory.create()`, error said **"Type not Found"** which is clear sign that something is not right with WSDL.

Anyway I found another solution:

```
MethodToExecute = getattr(self.client.service, methodName)

try:
    response = MethodToExecute(*array)
except WebFault as e:
    response = e
```

So now I can call any method I selected, and add as much parameters as I want.

Hope my solution will help some one.